# Route sound over SSH

Tags: macos, ssh, audio, sound-card

I want to play the sound from my current machine on a remote machine. Both machines have SSH installed, so SSH seems like a good option (if that's even possible). If not, I could alternatively use more dedicated software running on both machines.

Both machines in question are running OSX. To clarify, I want the sound which normally comes out of the client machine to come out of the server machine. I could just `afplay file.mp3` over SSH, but it would be good to just route all system sound (or at least from the browser, so I can play youtube videos for example).

Comment: [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/products/pro2/) Pro seems to have sound sharing, but it comes at $70 a year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on second thoughts: "playing stuff over the network" is usually referred to as "streaming". There are several ways to stream audio over the network. SSH is not often used in such scenarios.

Take a look at Jack: http://www.jackaudio.org/

and the NetJack: http://trac.jackaudio.org/wiki/WalkThrough/User/NetJack

that should get you started quickly..